# How to solve multiple instance issue on a work manager?

Tags: android, android-service, android-studio-3.0, android-workmanager

I have an worker to do a periodical task. and this worker is called in an activity on create. Every time the activity open there is a new instance created and do the same task in same time in multiple times. 
I called the task like this

```
task = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(BackgroundTask.class, 1000000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(task);
```

how to avoid creating multiple instance?
if there is no worker running i need to call the instance on create of the activity.

Comment: Try changing your activity type to `SingleInstance` in your manifest.

Comment: Share the code of your PeriodicWorkRequest class.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the fun [WorkManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html#enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(java.lang.String,%20androidx.work.ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy,%20androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest))

This function needs 3 params:

1. `tag` (string) so it would look for other previously created work requests with this tag
2. `strategy` to use when finding other previously created work requests. You can either replace the previous work or keep it
3. your new `work request`

For example in a kotlin project where I needed a location-capturing work to run every some time, I have created a fun that started the work like this:

```
fun init(force: Boolean = false) {

    //START THE WORKER
    WorkManager.getInstance()
            .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                    "locations",
                    if (force) ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE else ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
                    PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                            LocationsWorker::class.java,
                            PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS,
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                            .build())

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add tag to your WorkRequest (make it unique), and then check it's status by tag, and cancel when needed.
Or you can use `getId()` method, because it's autogenerated and cancel using this id.But this way you should save this id by yourself.

Or, for example, you can use `beginUniqueWork(...)` method

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager

Comment: 2 things: you can't schedule `PeriodicWork` in the `beginUniqueWork` method, and tags don't make a `WorkRequest` unique.